# LiteralPath does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: powershell

I am a beginner and do not know where the error is in my PowerShell script. After a long Google search and a lot of trial and error, I haven't found a solution.

Without LiteralPath the script works. However, I need LiteralPath so that I can use German letters like "ä" in paths.

```
$d = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "G:\ä\*.jpg" | resolve-path -LiteralPath | get-random -count 200
Move-Item -LiteralPath $d -destination G:\ä\ä
```

Comment: Oh, OK. I just want to make sure that I can use paths like c:\ä !\ correctly with the script. I have not been able to do that so far. How would I do that?

Comment: Try using parameter `-Filter` like `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "G:\ä" -Filter '*.jpg'` (no need for `resolve-path`)

Comment: I have now changed the code like this. Unfortunately, this one does not work either.

`code`
$d = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "G:\zufallswähl\" -Filter '*.jpg | resolve-path -LiteralPath | get-random -count 200
Move-Item -LiteralPath $d -destination "G:\zufallswähl\auswähl"
`code`

Comment: Oh, I have discovered a mistake. My new attempt, which unfortunately does not work either:
`code`
$d = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "G:\zufallswähl\" -Filter '*.jpg' | get-random -count 200

Move-Item -LiteralPath $d -destination "G:\zufallswähl\auswähl"
`code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`G:\ä\*.jpg` is a [*wildcard*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) pattern, so by definition it won't work with `-LiteralPath`, which uses its arguments *literally* (verbatim).

Non-ASCII-range characters such as `ä` should always work in file paths in PowerShell (with PowerShell-native commands), whether or not you use `-Path` with a wildcard pattern or `-LiteralPath` with a literal path.

The following streamlined version of your command *should* work; if it doesn't, the problem is most likely unrelated to non-ASCII-range characters in the paths:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath G:\ä -Filter *.jpg |
  Get-Random -Count 200 |
    Move-Item -Destination G:\ä\ä -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>